# Fill the gap in every row of ObjectListView how?

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview

Here's the problem, if you don't use check-state column in ObjectListView, there's always this gap in every row:
[image]

Especially when you want to use a small column to show row numbers:

[image]

This is so **NOT** looking good, how do you make each row expand to the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been adding an extra first empty column that has no no valueGetter and a width of 0 so it doesn't show, that way the following column starts on the left edge.
Add the following as the first column.

```
ObjectListView.ColumnDefn(title="", valueGetter="", maximumWidth=0)
```

Comment: Nice, this actually is a great workaround! Thanks a lot mate!